How to update a record in a mysql table with Confluent JDBC sink connector only if the record I'm going to insert is greater than the current record
I would like to know if it was possible to update a record via Confluent's jdbc sink connector only if the value I am inserting is greater than or equal to the current one. This is because my KSQLDB table does not delete data and therefore it is necessary to drop it and by doing this it resets the data already present in the mysql database. (I only use the ksqldb as a data aggregator and calculator, I wouldn't need to keep the data up there).
I tried with stored procedure but the connector ignores it...
I also tried inserting the query but here too the connector ignores it...
